# Problems with CKEditor dialog on top of Bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, code-snippets

I have included a plugin [here](http://ckeditor.com/addon/insertpre), to include code snippets on my site using CKEditor. With this, I found that people have problems with CKEditor dialog boxes and Bootstrap's modal window. Any dialog box opened isn't focused on, and text can't be entered.

A solution was found [here](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Issue-with-Twitter-Bootstrap). This fixes my issues with other dialog boxes, but not the one that opens with this pre tag plugin. Does anyone have any advice to get code snippets to work properly in CKEditor and Bootstrap?

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {
  modal_this = this
  $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
    if (modal_this.$element[0] !== e.target && !modal_this.$element.has(e.target).length 
    && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') 
    && !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
      modal_this.$element.focus()
    }
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding the condition

```
&& !$(e.target.parentNode).hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea')
```

now it works! Hopefully that helps anybody with this same issue.